# How to make time slots(for a particular date and time) not appear after a person has booked it in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am creating a website in which there is a form where you can book appointments(for doctors)..The issue I am facing is that, if a particular timeslot(for the particular date and time) has been selected it should not appear anymore on the form, but I have no clue on how to do it

The form looks like this(This is returned from the **index** function in **views.py**)

```
 <section id="appointment" data-stellar-background-ratio="3">
      <div class="container">
           <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                     <img src="{%  static 'images/appointment-image.jpg' %}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                     <!-- CONTACT FORM HERE -->
                     <form id="appointment-form" role="form" method="post" action="{% url 'test' %}">
                          {% csrf_token %}

                          <!-- SECTION TITLE -->
                          <div class="section-title wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                               <h2>Make an appointment</h2>
                          </div>

                          <div class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.8s">
                               <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Full Name">
                               </div>

                               <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email">
                               </div>

                               <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <label for="date">Select Date</label>
                                    <input type="date" name="date" value="" class="form-control">
                               </div>

                               <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <label for="select">Select Department</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="drop">
                                    {% for entry in items %}
                                         <option>{{ entry.category }}</option>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    </select>
                               </div>

                               <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <label for="select">Select Time</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="drop1">
                                    {% for entry in times %}
                                         <option>{{ entry.time }}</option>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    </select>
                               </div>

                               <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <label for="telephone">Phone Number</label>
                                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
                                    <label for="Message">Additional Message</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                    <button type="submit" class="form-control" id="cf-submit" name="submit">Submit Button</button>
                               </div>
                          </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

           </div>
      </div>
 </section>
```

The **views.py**, the test function saves the form(into database) and sends the email:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from .models import Form, categories, Doctors, News, timeslot
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

def index(request):
    time = timeslot.objects.all()
    item  = categories.objects.all() # use filter() when you have sth to filter ;)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selected_item = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=request.POST.get('item_id'))
        selected_item2 = get_object_or_404(time, pk=request.POST.get('time_id'))
        # get the user you want (connect for example) in the var "user"
        categories.item = selected_item
        categories.save()
        timeslot.time = selected_item2
        timeslot.save()

        # Then, do a redirect for example

    return render(request, 'website/index.html', {'items':item, 'times':time }) 

def test(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        name=request.POST['name']
        email=request.POST['email']
        date=request.POST['date']
        drop=request.POST.get('drop', False)
        time=request.POST.get('drop1', False)
        phone=request.POST['phone']
        message1=request.POST['message']
        
        message = "Name: "+ name + "\n" + "email: "+ email + "\n" + "Date of appointment: " + date + "\n" + "Time: " + time + "\n" "Service: " + drop + "\n" + "Number: " + phone + "\n" + "Special Message: "+ message1

        #send an email
        send_mail(
            'Make appointment for ' + name, #subject
            message, #the msg
            email, #from email
            ['madhavm2002@gmail.com'] #to email
            )
        #this is used to get the class from the models and then uses the variables assigned here to give value to the variables in models
        form=Form(name = name, email = email, date = date, time= time, drop = drop, phone = phone, msg1= message1)
        #this used the save method to save the object into the database
        form.save()
        return render(request, 'website/test.html', {'name':name})
    else:
        return render(request, 'website/index.html')
```

The **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models

class Form(models.Model):
    msg_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    date = models.DateField()
    drop = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    time = models.TimeField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    msg1 =  models.CharField(max_length=500)
    status = models.IntegerField(default = 0)


class categories(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class timeslot(models.Model):
    time = models.TimeField(max_length=80)
```

PS: the timeslots looke like 9am,10am,11am...1pm,2pm etc.
The categories give objects like "dental","physio" etc

Do tell how to solve this issue thanks

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) From that link: "Answerable questions don't ask how to implement a feature, they ask how to accomplish a programming task (among other things)." In other words, your question needs to be more focused rather than asking how to add a whole feature to your program.

Comment: oh ok sorry man.. thanks for info

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you'll need to have something to indicate available timeslots, then with a query joined to your appointments you'd have a condition in your template that that checks if the timeslot already has an appointment (or not) and act accordingly. This is a fairly broad question - see Brian's note.